# Permalink change during save of post

Tags: permalinks

I do have a strange behavior in the backend of wordpress during save of an page:

1. I do have an existing page with an valid permalink
   (pagetitle = A -> permalink = B)
2. I remove the permalink
3. I update the page and the system is generating an new permalink -> the title of the page -> the page can be accessed with the new permalink (pagetitle = A -> permalink = A)
4. I update the page without changes again -> the system changes the permalink to an new link. (pagetitle = A -> permalink = C-3)

The new name of the permalink is an existing page title extended with the number prefix to avoid duplicates.

Is there an Filter or Action I can use which is triggered during the permalink change in the backend - so that I can dedug the source of trouble? Or does anybody know this behavior?

**Update:**
The problem is related to an metabox on the each page. The content of an dropdownbox needs an WP_Query which results in this behavior.

many THX Martin

Comment: Are you using any plugins that fiddle with the permalinks ("custom permalinks" etc)?

Comment: it's my own plugin causing the problem. :(